# How to merge/overwrite two JSON object in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, merge

I want to merge two JSON files while the data overwrites itself in the main JSON file.

My main object is the following:

```
{
      "data": [
         {
            "name": "name1",
            "gender": "male",
            "age": "20",
            "subject": "Python",
            "pass": "No"
           }
      ]
    }
```

"new data.json" needs to be overridden with the following:

```
 {
  "data": [
     {
        "name": "name1",
        "subject": "Python",
        "pass": "Yes"
       }
  ]
}
```

The result object should be:

```
{
  "data": [
     {
        "name": "name1",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": "20",
        "subject": "Python",
        "pass": "Yes"          //updated
       }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use the built-in Python [`update`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-update-method/) method for dictionaries, which updates the current dictionary with values of a new one while keeping old data present.

For your case (assuming you always need to update the FIRST element in the array within the `"data"` key):

```
original_data = {
      "data": [
         {
            "name": "name1",
            "gender": "male",
            "age": "20",
            "subject": "Python",
            "pass": "No"
           }
      ]
    }

new_data =  {
  "data": [
     {
        "name": "name1",
        "subject": "Python",
        "pass": "Yes"
       }
  ]
}

original_data["data"][0].update(new_data["data"][0]) #this updates the original JSON
```

Comment: This. Was about to ^^
Question: why is the nested dictionary inside a list?